# How can I get the actionName in a ActionFilter？

Tags: asp.net-mvc, action-filter

this is my old code

---

```
    protected override bool OnPreAction(string actionName, System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        if ("|Register|RegisterPage|Login|LoginPage|Logout|Service".ToLower().Contains(actionName.ToLower()))
        {
            return base.OnPreAction(actionName, methodInfo);
        }

        Customer = CustomerHelper.GetCustomer();

        if (Customer.IsSeccessedLogin())
        {
            return base.OnPreAction(actionName, methodInfo);
        }

        Response.Redirect("Login.html");
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Glad you're looking for a better way.  That is....  a little scary :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
string actionName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
```

Answer (score 32):

FYI, as of RC1, you do it like this:

```
filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName
```